# How to convert multiple nested JSON files into single CSV file using python?

Tags: json, csv

I have about 200 nested JSON files with varying levels of nesting from one to three. Each JSON file consist of more than thousand data points. The keys of the values are same in all the files. My objective is to combine the data in all the files in a tabular format in a single CSV file so that I can read all the data and analyze it. I am looking for a simpler python code with brief explanation of each steps of the code to help in understanding the whole sequence of the code.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to 1) have properly-formatted JSON, and 2) contain the code you've written, where you're stuck, expected vs actual output, errors, etc. Currently the only thing you've included is a bit of JSON (which is not formatted, making it difficult to read).

Comment: Also, be sure to tag the language you're using. There are so many ways to do something like this (custom code, command-line tools, etc). This is too broad, as written (since it's just a basic requirement).

Comment: @HarshSaini - this isn't the place to promote products, services, frameworks, tools... The OP can search the web for various conversion tools.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your response. This is the format I have all the JSON files. In this post I only included two rows of a single file to represent the content of all files.  I don't have a background of using any programming language, however I have python installed on my pc. I have 200 JSON nested JSON files that I need to convert into single csv file.  Please let me know the easiest way to achieve my objective.

Comment: @HarshSaini I have tried this website but it only allows me to convert one file at a time. I need to convert atleast 200 files at a time.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please let me know what more information I can provide that can help to get this done.

Comment: yea @DavidMakogon totally agree with you, but the question doesn't specify how he wants to convert. So, I thought he might need some tools or something similar.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad - the most important thing is to show what you've done so far. And you've ask for the "easiest" way to achieve your objectives. There's no way to know what would be easiest for you. You haven't even specified a programming language, so right now, this question is simply too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet.
First of all install `pandas` using

```
pip install pandas
```

After that, you can use this code to convert JSON files to CSV.

```py
# code to save all data to a single file

import pandas as pd
import glob
path = './path to directory/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)

data_frames = []

for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    data_frames.append(pd.read_json(f))
    f.close()

pd.concat(data_frames).to_csv("data.csv")
```

```py
# code to save CSV data to individual files

import pandas as pd
import glob
path = './path to directory/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    jsonData = pd.read_json(f.read())
    jsonData.to_csv(f.name+".csv")
    f.close()
```

Comment: I really don't understand what's happening here but... you've now posted an answer to a question that had no specific details at all: no effort, no code, no anything. And now you're creating offsite resources for your code? (this is completely outside of site guidelines - everything needs to be self-contained). And as for debugging: the OP would need to post a separate question. It's literally impossible to do anything with unformatted python in a comment, since indentation is a critical part of the language.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad - pasting code into a comment isn't really helpful, *especially* when it comes to python code, which is dependent on spacing.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You are right, I understood your point that I have created a mess in this post. Let me repost what I want to achieve. 
I have about 200 nested JSON files with varying levels of nesting from one to three. In my question I shared the sample of two data points to help in understanding how the data looks like in all the files. Each JSON file consist of more than thousand data points. My objective is to combine the data in all the files in a tabular format in a single excel or CSV file so that I can read all the data and anaylze it.

Comment: Since I don't have a coding background so I posted this question in this forum to get guidance on how to achieve this task. I have python installed in my pc if that can help me to achieve this task. Also, is there a way I can use MATLAB to achieve this task. Any guidance in this regard shall be very helpful to me.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad - honestly, the first step is to not post more details in comments. Worse, you're posting more details in comments to an answer. You should *edit your question* to be very specific. For example, you just snuck in a mention of MATLAB, which appears nowhere in your original question (and makes this current answer invalid, really, aside from the reasons I've already given).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Alright, I will edit my question to make it more specific. I am new to this forum and this is my first post/question that's why I am having trouble with the way questions are asked in this forum.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad go through site tour you will get a gist how it works https://stackoverflow.com/tour